# How to set proxy for my application through Settings/Option/Preferences forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy, application-settings

I'm building an C# application using VS2015 and I have a problems: 
- I have a Prefernces forms with Proxy connection Option. 
- How to set up Proxy connection for my application (for any forms)? 
- Save it (proxy config) as a file. 
- Load it when Application starts

Comment: What do you mean proxy connection instead of true connection string

Comment: I want to allow users the option to configure the connection.

Comment: Like this: https://s32.postimg.org/5qx0zkmz9/Capture.png